# cc1.exe System Error - libwinpthread-1.dll missing - But it isn't

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw

I recently downloaded MinGW-w64 from Sourceforge onto my external hard drive, where all the files reside in:

`E:\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1\mingw64\bin`

When I try compiling my first "Hello World" program using gcc on Windows 8.1, I get a cc1.exe System Error, that tells me

> The program can't start because libwinpthread-1.dll is missing.
>   Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

And yet, libwinpthread-1.dll (all 54,784 bytes of it) is sitting right there in the very same directory as gcc.exe. Do I really need to reinstall everything, or is something else going wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will get better answers if you ask one concrete question at a time, and give more details.

Comment: Try adding "E:\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1\mingw64\bin" to your PATH

Comment: Alternative is to CD to the bin directory where g++.exe is

Answer (score 27):

I know this post is over two years old but I recently had the same problem when using CMake.

I fixed it by adding MinGW to the "Path" Envionment Variable:
I am using Windows 10 Home.

1. "Windows Key"+ Pause/Break
2. On the left there is "Advanced System settings"
3. On the bottom of this window there is a button called "Environment Variables"
4. Click on the name "Path"
5. Click on "edit" under **System Variables**
6. Add your MinGW directory there. For me that was `C:\MinGW\bin`

I Hope I could help. If not you, maybe someone else.

Comment: To clarify, the "Path" you click on should also be under "System variables" (not under "User variables for ___").

Answer (score 5):

I consider it best to statically link the libraries needed.  This means that the executable can be run anywhere, without having to look for them.  To do this, use the -static flag in the linker.

For example:

g++.exe -o ......\bin\connect.exe obj\Release\src\connect.o -static

Comment: How exactly does this help? Isn't the problem here that gcc itself has not been built with static  libwinpthread? Are you suggesting all he needs to do is recompile gcc from scratch, statically linking gcc to libwinpthread before recompiling his own code using the new gcc he built?

Comment: @crobar This has fixed it for me, since I'm the developer of my code. Adding -static allowed me to ship my tool with all dependencies included.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this.

In codeblocks go to `settings` > `compiler` and mark these i have shown in picture

[image: solution]

Hope it will work.

Comment: I notice that checking `Static linking [-static]` without explicitly doing so for `libgcc` and `libstdc++` still worked. Also, I had read that C++ 17 ISO standard is currently a widely accepted standard. Your screenshot was a good reminder for me to enable that option, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're missing `libwinpthread-1.dll` it means you're missing the entire MinGW toolchain and you'll have many more problems with other DLLs. Instead of adding this single DLL, install the entire MinGW toolchain to avoid further issues.

1. Install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) x64
2. Open `MSYS2 MinGW x64` command prompt
3. Run `pacman -S base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` to install the GCC toolchain (all components)
4. Add `c:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the System PATH

Answer (score 1):

I've used following to fix:

```
pacman -Fsy "libwinpthread-1.dll"
pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git
```

Answer (score -1):

the dll files are already in the application file but what you need to do is copy the dll files and paste it in windows system32

Comment: Please never do something like this, leave the operating system folders alone, unless you really know what you are doing.