# gcc.exe error Missing libwinpthread-1.dll, but it is not missing

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I attempted the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907304/cc1-exe-system-error-libwinpthread-1-dll-missing-but-it-isnt) which said to add MingW to the system path, but this did not work. I installed MingW alongside Codeblocks, and compiling works just fine. However, I have had issues with the the `make` command, which has led me to trying to see if there is issues with my compiler. Running `gcc.exe` in `CMD` gave the error that `libwinpthread-1.dll` was missing, but it clearly isn't. How can I get my computer to recognize it?

Comment: Which directory do you add to `PATH`? Which directory is `libwinpthread-1.dll` in? And which `PATH` environment variable did you change? How did you change it?

Comment: I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` to my path. `libwinpthread-1.dll` is located in `bin`. I didn't change one, I added it.

Comment: Having the exact same problem as you right now and it is enfuriating! It gives me an error for all the .dll files, but I can see them all in my /bin directory (and have also added it to path). Can't compile anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the same problem on my codeblocks going to `settings → compiler`, choosing "Searching directories" and then choosing "linker" tab below and adding the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
```

…(or your MingW installation). All libraries are linked statically.

CodeBlocks version 20.03